# Asp.net RabbitMQ can receive data but cannot update the Asp:label

Tags: c#, asp.net, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ to get real time data. I make the connection and am getting data successfully. I am able to print it in the Debug line, but its not updating my Label.

here is my code:

```
private void InitRabbit()
{

    factory.UserName = this.user;
    factory.Password = this.password;
    factory.HostName = this.host;
    factory.VirtualHost = "/";

    try
    {
        using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.ExchangeDeclare(realTimeExchange, "topic");
                string queueName = channel.QueueDeclare();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("QEH").Append(".").Append("QEH").Append(".*");
                channel.QueueBind(queueName, realTimeExchange, sb.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for messages");
                QueueingBasicConsumer consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
                channel.BasicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
                while (true)
                {
                    BasicDeliverEventArgs e = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body));
                    string msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Body);
                    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    Alerts alert = ser.Deserialize<Alerts>(msg);
                    updatealert(alert); //for getting the Alerts which is my internal class
                }
            }
            rabbitrunning = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rabbit not running : " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here is my updatealert function:

```
private void updatealert(Alerts alert)
{
    alertext.Text = "Count " + alert.CarName;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("publish : " + alert.CarName);//its writting the message correctly but its not updating my Alertext label. 
}
```

Here is the update panel structure:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
         <asp:Label ID="alertext" runat="server" Text="change" ></asp:Label>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="change" ></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Get Real Data" />
```

How do I change the label text while rabbitMQ is updating the content?

**UPDATES : After Long Trail and error I found that the rabbit is sending a lot of messages per second so the Update panel is not updating fast , so I tried to put the Update panel job in other thread but I have not succeeded , is there any advice how to update the panel with handling very fast process ?**

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling UpdatePanel1.Update(); after setting the text of your label

Comment: I have do that , it updates once then it disconnected my rabbit and said : " The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional." then I edit the Mode to Conditional , then its not updating again .. I thing I have to put the updatealert on other thread ? how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ will not send a lot of messages per second unless you are propagating a lot of messages per second. If you are trying to capture a lot of messages per second I think you should rethink your choice of technology. ASP.Net will work better as a bridge to connect to an HTML5 document say use it to redeliver the json file you are getting to a websocket on the HTML5 page since that will provide you better fine grain control on the postback.

Comment: Thank you moshe , I worked on your advice and used your Yaws websocket  and integrated with HTML5 , but the superwebsocket was having issues with 3G connections even we use SSL and wss . Regards...

Comment: @TamerHatoum what kind of issues were you having with superwebsocket on 3G?